# boost/regex/v4/regex_workaround.hpp:199:37: error: 'sizeInBytes' was not declared in this scope

Tags: regex, boost

When I compile my program with boost regex, I got a compiling error as below:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/regex/v4/regex.hpp:32:0,
             from /usr/local/include/boost/regex.hpp:31,
             from ProcessAffinityManager.cpp:38:
/usr/local/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_workaround.hpp: In function 'size_t boost::re_detail::strcpy(char*, const char*)':
/usr/local/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_workaround.hpp:199:37: error: 'sizeInBytes' was not declared in this scope
```

But when I examine the source file `regex_workaround.hpp`, `sizeInBytes` is a argument, the error should not be here.

Comment: I think we need more information here - like what version of boost, what compiler, and a sample program.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the commentator that more info is required..

However I had the exact same issue in a project I am working on using minGW 4.8.1
After a little investigation I found that someone added a macro hack to our project of the sort:

```
#define strcpy_s(A,B,C) strcpy(A,C)
```

The idea I guess was to solve a compatibility issue with  between VS and MinGW. VS defines "secure" versions of many C string functions such as strcpy_s(A,B,C).
A lot of libraries when compiling on windows use these versions of the functions, however they are missing for older versions of VS and for MinGW

Boost::regex solves this issue by trying to define a strcpy_s for environments that might miss it. It clashes with the ugly hack of trying to force strcpy_s calls to use strcpy

If your problem is like mine the solution is to find who added the strcpy_s hack and move to a solution of providing such a function